# Equations of motions uneven see-saw

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

How do I set up equations of motions for a see-saw where the distance between the masses $m_1,m_2$ to the pivot are given by $\ell_1, \ell_2$, respectively?  My idea was to first set one of the masses to zero. Then the system becomes a pendulum ($ \ell_1 \ddot{\theta} = g \sin (\theta)$)  but then I am not sure how to include the second mass so I guess this might not be a good approach. Furthermore, how would I set up the equations of motion if the position of the masses with respect to the pivot become time-dependent? I am aware how to do this just for a pendulum with varying length but for this case I am not sure.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your system is rotating about a pivot then the equation of motion is:

$$ \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} = \frac{T}{I} $$

where $T$ is the torque and $I$ is the moment of inertia. The torque may or may not be a function of $\theta$ depending on your system. Simply calculate the total torque by adding the torques created by your two masses then solve the resulting differential equation.